# PyPDF2.PdfFileReader hangs indefinitely

Tags: pypdf

I'm trying to read this pdf file (https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/cdrh_docs/pdf14/K141693.pdf) and am following these suggestions from SO

[Opening pdf urls with pyPdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751197/opening-pdf-urls-with-pypdf)

I have actually downloaded the file locally and am running the following code

```
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open("K141693.pdf")
pdf_read = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
```

but my code hangs indefinitely. I'm running Python 2.7 and here is the stacktrace.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ```
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/PoC/pdf_reader.py', wdir='C:/PoC')
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 880, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 87, in execfile
>       exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "C:/PoC/pdf_reader.py", line 13, in 
>       pdf_read = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py",
>   line 1084, in **init**
>       self.read(stream)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py",
>   line 1697, in read
>       line = self.readNextEndLine(stream)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py",
>   line 1938, in readNextEndLine
>       x = stream.read(1)
>
> KeyboardInterrupt

I came across another post here [PyPDF2 hangs on processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575468/pypdf2-hangs-on-processing) but that too doesn't have a response.

Comment: SAME. it's stuck in an infinite loop somehow. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: If you haven't added an issue on PyPDF2, including your code and the post and the PyPDF2 version, I suggest you should do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the file in binary ('rb') mode. (This works in Python 3:)

```
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open("K141693.pdf", "rb")
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
```

Comment: Still hanging up.